# Paste part of URL into php/javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitch

I'm very fresh to php/js, and need some help.

My URL goes like https://example.com/embed.php?ch=GOESHERE, and I am wanting to make the site figure out what the URL says after "?ch=" part and use it in a function.

So if the URL is "https://example.com/embed.php?ch=channel" I want "channel" to be pasted in the function.

The javascript provided is ([can be found here](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/embed/#embedding-everything))

```
new Twitch.Embed("twitch-embed", {
  width: 1255,
  height: 500,
  channel: "channel"
});
```

I'd like whatever the `?ch=` url is to be where the `channel: "channel"` currently is.

Sorry if I'm not making much sense, but I'm trying to explain what I can.

Appreciate all help.

**EDIT**
I am using

```
new URL(location.href).searchParams.get('ch')
const params = new URL(location.href).searchParams;
const ch = params.get('ch');
console.log(ch);
```

to find the param I need. Now how can I paste this param into the `channel: "channel"` section where I need it?

Comment: what is `Embed`? what is the argument `embed` for? which part are you having issue with? creating the URL in javascript or "reading" the URL in PHP?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the value from the GET parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

you need to get value first with this

```
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

**Usage**

```
// query string: ?ch=value
var ch = getParameterByName('foo'); // "value"
```

after that add your value to your array. tell me if its work !

Comment: Please explain what the function does to those who may not already know!

Comment: everyone come from newbie, we need to help and i need point  with point i can discuss more :(

Comment: @TrevorClarke Updated my OP with another question.

Comment: @JanHenning assuming you have run the code that you put in the edit, all you have to do it type channel: ch instead of channel: "channel"  hope it works

Comment: @TrevorClarke Ah, got it! I forgot to remove the quotation marks.Thanks so much! Works like a charm.

Comment: No worries, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Solved using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  new URL(location.href).searchParams.get('ch')
  const params = new URL(location.href).searchParams;
  const ch = params.get('ch');

  new Twitch.Embed("twitch-embed", {
    width: 1225,
    height: 500,
    channel: ch
  });
</script>
```